# How to match string between two delimiters and append a string after

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have a file with the contents like below:

```
[idx1]
path1 = $test/idx1/test
path2 = $test/idx1/test
path3 = $test/idx1/test

[idx2]
path1 = $test/idx2/test
path2 = $test/idx2/test
path3 = $test/idx2/test
```

Is there a way to match all strings like idx1, idx2 between the delimiters and append a string after each match.

```
[idx1_string]
path1 = $test/idx1_string/test
path2 = $test/idx1_string/test
path3 = $test/idx1_string/test

[idx2]
path1 = $test/idx2_string/test
path2 = $test/idx2_string/test
path3 = $test/idx2_string/test
```

Comment: maybe `echo "path2 = $test/idx2/test" | awk -F/ '{$2=$2"_string"}1'` gives you an idea. Good luck.

Comment: Why not `_string` after `[idx2]` (second paragraph) when you have it after `[idx1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but it seems like you **might** be asking how to do either of the following:

```
$ sed 's:/\([^/]*\)/:/\1_string/:' file
[idx1]
path1 = $test/idx1_string/test
path2 = $test/idx1_string/test
path3 = $test/idx1_string/test

[idx2]
path1 = $test/idx2_string/test
path2 = $test/idx2_string/test
path3 = $test/idx2_string/test

$ sed 's:\([[/]\)\([^/]*\)\([]/]\):\1\2_string\3:' file
[idx1_string]
path1 = $test/idx1_string/test
path2 = $test/idx1_string/test
path3 = $test/idx1_string/test

[idx2_string]
path1 = $test/idx2_string/test
path2 = $test/idx2_string/test
path3 = $test/idx2_string/test
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple extended regex expression for `sed` that will accomplish your goal is:

```
sed -r 's/idx(\w+)/idx\1_string/' file
```

The expression makes use of the word match `\w` which matches `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

To edit the file in-place add `-i` as an option, and to preserve a copy of the original with the `.bak` extension when you edit in-place, simply add the option as `-i.bak`.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input file, an example use and output would be:

```
$ sed -r 's/idx(\w+)/idx\1_string/' file
[idx1_string]
path1 = $test/idx1_string/test
path2 = $test/idx1_string/test
path3 = $test/idx1_string/test

[idx2_string]
path1 = $test/idx2_string/test
path2 = $test/idx2_string/test
path3 = $test/idx2_string/test
```

Comment: What if the string idx isn't consistent throughout the file? Can I do something like this?

sed -r 's/\[(\w+)\]|\/(\w+)\//<reference to capture groups>_string/' testfile

Comment: How would I reference the capture groups?

Comment: When you reference a capture-group, you do so using a back-reference. So if you have two capture-groups, you reference them with `\1` and `\2`, respectively. So from your comment you would do `sed -r 's/[(\w+)]|\/(\w+)\//\1\2/' testfile`  (adding whatever you need before, between or after `...\1...\2...`)

Answer (score 2):

If you like to change all

```
sed -r 's/(idx[0-9])/\1_string/' file
[idx1_string]
path1 = $test/idx1_string/test
path2 = $test/idx1_string/test
path3 = $test/idx1_string/test

[idx2_string]
path1 = $test/idx2_string/test
path2 = $test/idx2_string/test
path3 = $test/idx2_string/test
```

If header should not be changed.

```
sed -r 's|(idx[0-9])/|\1_string/|' file
[idx1]
path1 = $test/idx1_string/test
path2 = $test/idx1_string/test
path3 = $test/idx1_string/test

[idx2]
path1 = $test/idx2_string/test
path2 = $test/idx2_string/test
path3 = $test/idx2_string/test
```